# Getting the Tag Number of Touched Object

Tags: ios6, tags, addsubview

I have a button.  Every time the user clicks on it, the application will instantiate the **UIImageView** (imageview), assigning a unique number to its tag.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 240)];
    NSUInteger currentag = [self UniqueNum]; // Assigning a unique number to the tag variable
    [self.view addSubview:imageview];
    imageview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    imageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    imageview.tag = currentag;
}
```

My goal is to get the tag number of the UIImageView copy that the user touches.  With the following code, what I actually get is the tag number of the UIImageView copy that the application last created.  How can I improve it so that the application will point to the tag number of the touched object?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if([touch view] == imageview) {
        NSLog(@"Tag: %i",imageview.tag);
    }    
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using UIButtons with custom images here rather than UIImageViews if you need interaction.

Add this when you add the button:

```
   [imageview addTarget:self action:@selector(someMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
```

And then just cast the `sender` in `someMethod` (your declaration) to UIView to get its tag.

BTW, the method signature of someMethod goes something like this:

```
-(void) someMethod:(id)sender
```

You can optionally also add an event parameter, but that doesn't seem to be needed here.

Comment: Ahhh...  That's smart.  Let me see it.  Thanks.

Comment: Hmm...  I get an error on 'imageview' that says 'No visible @interface for 'UIImageView' declares the selector 'addTarget:action:forControlEvents.'

Comment: @TBlue Damnit, forgot that was only for instances of classes that inherit from UIControl.If you still want to use this approach, change your UIImageViews to UIButtons and set the image.

Comment: Yes.  I've just figured out that I could only do it with a UIButton.

Comment: Okay.  I guess I can use UIPanGestureRecognizer for UIImageView.

Comment: UITapGestureRecognizer is better.